# How to extract a string from a string?

Tags: objective-c, regex, substring

I'm trying to find how to extract "**2013-05-01/game1**" from "**/games/usa/2013-05-01/game1.html**", but I don't how to do that. I already tried some Regex on it but it didn't work. And I also don't know if this would be the best way. This is what I have tried so far.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]-{2}\//\.*$)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *newSearchString = [regex firstMatchInString:opening_time options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [opening_time length])];
NSString *substr = [opening_time substringWithRange:newSearchString.range];
NSLog(@"%@", substr);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you rely on the format surrounding the string? Will it always be like your example?

Comment: yes, always like that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use `NSString`'s `componentsSeparatedByString:` method. Here's an example

```
NSString *str = [@"/games/usa/2013-05-01/game1.html" stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSArray *components = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [components objectAtIndex:3], [components objectAtIndex:4]];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Of course, this would rely on the fact that the format never changes, and this most likely won't work if it does change.

Comment: Regex is often overkill for 90% of cases when it is used. Good on you for pointing out a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/[^.]+"
```

or this:

```
@"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/.+?(?=\\.html)"
```

Comment: That works too, but i'll keep the other one as the answer based on what @hd1 said! But thanks!